# QComboBox, PyQt5 - Numbers in Item strings are reordered

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I'm encountering the following (weird) behaviour when adding items to a QComboBox using PyQt5:
The items are all added from a list of strings, but they are displayed correctly only when selected. When appearing in the drop-down list, the order of the numbers contained in the strings is changed:

```
my_list = ["200 x 300",
           "240 x 550",
           "400 x 120"]

# same list, but with the correct multiplication symbol:               
my_list2 = ["200 × 300",
            "240 × 550",
            "400 × 120"]

combobox1.addItems(my_list)
combobox2.addItems(my_list2)
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Why does this happen? What can I do to fix this or is it a bug?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. What platform are you on, and have you set a stylesheet on the combo-boxes, or used any other funky settings? (For me, a vanilla combo-box has the text left-aligned).

Comment: A funky setting like `setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)` will produce that behaviour. So not a bug.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I had used Qt Designer and for some reason the layout direction was set to Qt.RightToLeft.